# Python - Using subclasses in non-specific order

Tags: python, class, jython, sikuli

I've been introducing myself to Python (Jython) with the SikuliX Script, so please excuse me if this a basic question. In Sikulix, there is a class called Pattern that accepts optional sub classes, for example `similar` and `targetOffset`. These sub classes are interchangeable in the order they are used.

For example.

```
#image1 and image2 are the same

# targetOffset before similar
image1 = Pattern("file.png").targetOffset(0, -50).similar(0.8)

# similar before targetOffset
image2 = Pattern("file.png").similar(0.8).targetOffset(0, -50)
```

How do I replicate the above in my own classes?

Comment: Looks like both similar and targetOffset are methods and not sub classes. Both of them return pattern object so it is possible to operate like the way provided in the code here. Check this link https://github.com/sikuli/sikuli/blob/958dad917900eb5791e0fb7254f81f8018a4b470/docs/source/pattern.rst

Comment: That makes perfect sense. I don't know why I thought they were classes. Thank you for the explanation and the link.